# What is the proper tagging for this question with mixed rules?

Tags: discussion

I'm referring to the following question:

[The else statement replacement in the fewest bytes?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26186/the-else-statement-replacement-in-the-fewest-bytes)

> The winner is the one with most votes, probably the most creative. Plus, the more the bytes, the less your chance of winning. The score formula is: `score = votes * 10 - bytes`, so the more bytes you use, the less your score.
>
> Highest score wins.

IIRC, [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) are mutually exclusive. Not so sure about [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).

Answer (score 3):

With the scoring rules *as written*, I would tag it with [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) only.

From the code challenge [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-challenge/info) (emphasis mine):

> The most common problem specific to a code challenge is that its winning criterion is highly subjective (i.e. each answer is equally valid) or that **multiple, conflicting winning criteria** exist.

In addition, the code golf [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) excerpt says:

> A competition which scores on a **mixture of source length and some other criterion** should be tagged [code-challenge] instead.

You can see several examples of this sort of criteria by browsing the code challenge tag. For example:

[What's my name? Produce the name of the language indirectly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1091/14215)

[When does (x == x+2)?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7165/14215)

[Implement ROT-47... in ROT-47](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22751/14215)

[Convert number to comma separated number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4499/14215)

[Arbitrary Base Conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1620/14215)

All have some degree of subjectivity in addition to the other criteria. In some cases, votes are simply used as tie-breakers. In others, there *seem* to be no criteria at all, and the tag was edited in by someone later because it lacked one.

To be honest, [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) could be considered a bit of a mess, but it's useful to have something to fall back on when none of the other tags fit *quite* right.

Comment: The purpose of [tag:code-challenge] is to be a catch-all for unusual *objective* winning criteria.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd argue that "objective" could be removed from the tag wiki, based on the way the tag is *actually* used (and edited in by high-rep users and mods). See edit.

Comment: Looking at those examples I see one pop-con which somehow avoided being closed despite predating [tag:popularity-contest] by over a year; one question with no winning criteria; one example of how [tag:code-challenge] is supposed to be used; and two more questions with no winning criteria. With the exception of the one which uses it correctly, they're all at least 18 months old. I think that it would be better to close the ones without criteria rather than to change the tag to accommodate them.

Comment: Do you suggest a replacement that *would* fit mixed subjective/objective criteria, or is it your opinion that it is never appropriate?

Comment: To answer the direct question, I favour the original scope of the site, which is still reflected in the help pages (objective criteria only), and while it's possibly too late to row back on pop-con, I'm not in favour of splintering it into hybrids. To answer a more general question, as I said in my answer, KISS. Having a secondary criterion for a pure tie-breaker is sometimes sensible, but I don't see much argument for weighted mixtures of criteria.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a winning criterion tag which fits.

- It's not [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) because the score depends on votes.
- It's not [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) because the score depends on code length.

Given that the weight given to votes is far greater than that given to objective criteria, [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) is the closest, but I think it would be better to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and change the criterion to either be objective or subjective.